# How to Make a Plesk Windows server work with external nameservers

Tags: windows, dns, plesk

I have a Plesk windows server and I want it to work with my 3 existing nameservers. I have configured the nameservers  to accept zone-files exported from the Windows server but I do not know how to make the windows server export zone files to them. 
My research has led to making a batch file which I schedule with the windows task scheduler.
What do I include in the batch file to achieve this? I need like a typical zone exporting script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what is "accept zone files exported from the Windows server". I would guess you've setup so-called slave DNS zone on your existing name servers. If so, now you would need to go "Tools & Settings > DNS Template > Transfer Restrictions Template" and allow Zone Transfer to those servers. If everything done right, your existing name servers will pull zone from Plesk and distribute it further.